# Setting up cache to consider file-modification date/time

Tags: php, caching

I'm having problems with serving CSS files from PHP. For test I'm just loading content from existing CSS file into PHP variable and than echo it. I want to set headers to allow caching of file until it was modified.

**PHP code**

```
  $css_file_path = "path-to-existing-css-file";
  $file_content = file_get_contents ($css_file_path);
  $fmtime = date ("r", filemtime ($css_file_path));

  header ("Content-type: text/css");
  header ("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff");
  header ("Last-Modified: " . $fmtime);

  die ($file_contents);
```

This is done by simple PHP code as shown above. For some reason it's never cached (tested in latest Firefox only).

I have tried to put this line before die() function to test it.

```
  echo date ("r", time());
```

And it gets updated all the time. I'm such a caching noob, I admit it, so all I want to do is to make file being cached until new modification arrives.

So far, I have read tones of different posts here and web-wide and mostly found nothing or very poor information on this subject.

What am I missing and is it possible to achieve at all?

Comment: After I typed my answer, one (quite important) question popped up in my mind: if this is really only about reading the css-file and sending it to the browser, why don't you let apache/nginx handle this? That process is much more efficient in serving files than PHP is, and will (if properly set up) behave similar as I described in my answer

Comment: Sometimes i have to clear cache in my browser to get things work. Actually, most of time my Firefox dont get updated css from server, sometimes for hours if i dont do cache cleaning. I just wanted to do something more efficient than letting apache and browser do things on their own.

Comment: Verify in the browsers debugging-console (network-tab) that apache is sending the correct headers for caching. Try for example adding a `<FilesMatch "\.(css)$"> Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, must-revalidate" </FilesMatch>` to your apache-config. If you can get it working correctly within apache, I think that's the most preferable solution. But in the end, thats up to you ;)

Comment: Yep, this is nice solution. Wondering if apache-config is accessible at every server? Servers I'm using are fine but can't rely on that if that's not applicable in every situation because I don't know what kind of servers my clients use. That's major reason why I wanted PHP handles everything - independence.

Comment: In most shared hosting environments (where you can't edit the main apache-config-file like you could on localhost/any private server) you can add a `.htaccess`-file with those entries, however I'm not making you any promises ;) However (2nd important question), is this really an issue in a production-enviroment? For development I understand, but on production  CSS normally seldom changes. And by adding a `must-revalidate` forces the browser to check the file EVERY time the clients navigates to the next page on your website.

Comment: Yes, this is a huge issue and it's been an issue for a quite a time now. I'm real noob on this and trying (and learning) to fix it on global level. At the moment I'm forcing file reload with get parameter in LINK tag of HTML and I will till I find more elegant solution. At the moment I have access to 175 different servers and want to avoid looking for different solution for every single one of them.

Comment: Anyway, found your answer more than usable. Thanx.

Comment: You're welcome. And final last comment for now ;) : If you ask me, adding a get-parameter in the link-tag _IS_ the most elegant solution. It both fixes the stale cached version problem as minimizes the number of (necesarry) requests to the server (and thus increases zero-to-visual page loading speed). I'm using this solution myself for 500+ websites, so I'm not totally new to this issue. Writing a helper-method like `function getVersionUrl($url) { return $url . '?version=' . filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT' . $url]); }` (very minimal implementation) avoids having to rewrite the url manually.

Comment: Thanx again. As people say, you live, you learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with

> I want to do is to make file being cached until new modification arrives

The only way a browser can know there is a new modification, is by asking the server whether their cached version is still valid.

This is done as followed:

```
1. Browser requests /style.css
GET /style.css

2. Server sends to browser
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Wed 2 Aug 2017 21:28:00 GMT
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=31536000

... file-contents ...

// 31536000 is about 1 year

3. Next time browser wants that file it sends
GET /style.css
If-Modified-Since: Wed 2 Aug 2017 21:28:00 GMT

4a. Your server can read that header, and verify if the file isn't modified after
    the given date. If it isn't, you can reply with a single:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified

... without sending the contents again 

4b. If your file was hower modified after Aug 2, you should sent a response simalar 
    as in step 2
```

So in code, step 2, add the Cache-Control-header:

```
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=31536000');
```

And step 4a, act to the If-Modified-Since request-header:

```
$css_file_path = "path-to-existing-css-file";
$fmtimestamp = filemtime ($css_file_path);

// Check header set by browser
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) && $fmtimestamp <= strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 304 Not Modified');
    die(); // We're done here
}

// Otherwise continue as ussualy
$file_content = file_get_contents ($css_file_path);
```

Alternative solution, without using the `If-Modified-Since`, but it depends on the situation if this is usable for you:

```
// Somewhere in your HTML
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css?version=<?php echo filemtime($pathToStyle.css) ?>" />
```

When your file changes, the link changes and the browser would see it as a new file. In that case you can leave the `must-revalidate`-part out of the `Cache-Control`-header and the browser won't reload the `style.css` unless the max-age expires or cache is cleaned up.

Comment: Hm, this looks like server-side caching, i'm talking about client-side (cache controlled by browser itself). In short, is there a way browser asks server for modification time of file and if it's not modified use one from own cache, otherwise download new version.

Comment: From a browser's standpoint it doesnt matter if file is created at run-time and downloaded or downloaded from server's cache... I want to stop downloads in the first place, not to download it from different location on server.

Comment: No this ISN'T server-side caching. This is exactly doing what you describe in your (first) comment. By sending the `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified` header to the browser, you are telling it nothing on the server changed and the browser can go ahead with its cached version

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanx. Let me test this.